# VS2015 Web Essential Duplicate Context Menu in Code Editor

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, web-essentials

I installed Web Essentials 2015.3 in VS2015 Pro and noticed that when I am in my cshtml file and right click on my editor I get a section of my context menu duplicated. How do I get rid of the extra ones?

[image]

Comment: Hi there, author of Glyphfriend here! This is the first I've seen of an issue like this, so I appreciate you posting it. I'm looking into the issue and reaching out to Mads, the author of Web Essentials to see if we can figure out what's going wrong. It almost seems as if two instances of the extension are loaded, but if there were somehow two instances of the menu, that could do it too. I'll keep you up to date once I get to the bottom of it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same duplicate context menu items in VS2015 CE with Web Essentials 2015.3 3.0.235 after installing Glyphfriend 2015 2.1.0.2. The context menus returned to normal after disabling or uninstalling Glyphfriend and restarting VS2015.